# Issue with adding Headers/Footers to PDF

Tags: .net, aspose, aspose.words, aspose.pdf

Aspose Version: 22.2.0
Code: .net

Out current process is as follows:

We Save a Docx as a PDF to a local directory
We load that PDF into a Document
We loop through each page of the document and add different Headers/Footers as needed based on client configuration.
We save the PDF file for access by the customers.
He Header/Footer being saved is primarily in HTML so we use the following code to add them to the pages.

[image]

The problem that is occurring during this process is that the text is duplicating in the Header/Footer of the document.

Here is the document being converted to PDF (This document was also created by Aspose)

[Docx before it is PDF](https://rocksolidtechnologies-my.sharepoint.com/:w:/g/personal/lthorpe_rocksolidtechnologies_onmicrosoft_com/EV6AjjdbGQNDgvri1wDpp-UBMXwsp4so_29ardhgGUMDFw?e=10Qewi)

Here is the PDF with the Headers/Footers and both duplicate. The header appears twice and the footers appear over the top of each other causing it to look garbled.

[Problem PDF](https://rocksolidtechnologies-my.sharepoint.com/:b:/g/personal/lthorpe_rocksolidtechnologies_onmicrosoft_com/ET817lqb0xdGrFuNQeiSwh4ByUgMu-1YSlPSn6LZ6AL3vQ?e=WicboQ)

I have tried to adjust the code with varying results, when adjusting and debugging the code I was able to get it to remove the duplication but that is due to the header being adding in the same location multiple times which causes the text to become bold. You can see what I’m referring to below on the 1st page the text looks bold and on the second it appears normal. When I would removed setting the margins is when the header stopped duplicating but then was appearing bold.

[PDF with slight adjustments](https://rocksolidtechnologies-my.sharepoint.com/:b:/g/personal/lthorpe_rocksolidtechnologies_onmicrosoft_com/EeziuVyevfdMpEIQUfOUZ4kBe80N2MojjbiI379OgAuL8g?e=Vm4FFB)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: Looks like similar issue (https://forum.aspose.com/t/issue-with-adding-headers-to-pdf/274985/) has been reported in Aspose.PDF official support forum where we have responded accordingly. We request you follow up there. This is Asad Ali and I am Developer Evangelist at Aspose.